# How do I convert an ISO 8601 date to DateTime type in ActiveJDBC?

Tags: java, activejdbc

The `toJson` method gives as result a date type with format **[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)**.

With console output, the `someEntityInstance.toString()` method produces:

```
{Valid=true, Activation_Date=2018-02-11 05:00:00.0, Creation_Date=2018-02-11 05:00:00.0}
```

But with the `someEntityInstance.toJson(false)` the date is converted to ISO 8601:

```
{Valid=true, Activation_Date=2018-02-11T05:00:00Z, Creation_Date=2018-02-11T05:00:00.0Z}
```

And when I try to save the object it generates an exception:

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-02-11T05:00:00Z' for column 'Activation_Date'
```

What do I need to do to automatically convert the generated date to the standard `DateTime` format?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJDBC is a [Pass-through framework](http://javalite.io/pass_through_framework). This means that the ***data type*** you set on a model:

```
model.set("activation_date", date);
```

and whatever you read from the database:

```
YourModel m = YourModel.findById(1);
Object activationCode = m.get("activation_code");
```

***can be different.***

Whenever you read something from the database, your attributes have types returned by the driver. However, when you set a value, you set the type too, and it is up to the driver to convert the type you set to the underlying DB type.

I have a feeling that the two examples you have are from different life-cycles of your model. In order to guard from this, you can write typed setters:

```
public class YourModel extends Model{
    public YourModel setActivactionDate(java.sql.Timestamp t){
      set("activation_date", t); 
    }
}
```

UPDATE: the `toJson` method does in fact convert to ISO format:
https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.java#L1047

What you can do is to add a date or timestamp converter:

http://javalite.io/data_conversions#converters

Comment: This is the code I have to get entity information:

`Local local = Local.findById(idLocal);
System.out.println(local.toString());
System.out.println(local.toJson(true));`

Comment: in your question, provide a DDL for your table and information on the database you are using.

Comment: also, exactly how do you save the object? Provide a snapshot of code that causes the issue

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1D9kyBN2 I have some translation to help non-Spanish speakers... in the original question.

Comment: How date converters are applied? What happens if I have a `LazyList` with tons of objects: `LazyList<Local> locales = Local.where("Id_Empresa = ?", idEmpresa);` ?

Comment: When I use the `locales.toJson(true)` it generates dates in ISO 8601 format. Does the date converter that you suggest, converts automatically dates to format compatible to MySQL's `DateTime` type?

Comment: converters  convert to Java types. It is a responsibility of the Mysql driver to convert to DB types from there.

Comment: reading your question, I need to understand how you store your model? Do you fill in values from a JSON document?